# KendoGrid : Discarding previously selected rows on grid.select()

Tags: kendo-grid

If a do a grid.select(row1), and then do a grid.select(row2), I mean to switch the selection from row1 to row2. But this doesn't happen; both rows are selected. To achieve the switching, I need to do a grid.clearSelection() before selecting again, but that fires the change event 2 times.

How can i select one row at a time programatically? By manually clicking on rows, the selection switches, and change event is only fired once. So I'm thinking there has to be a way to reproduce that programatically as well.

EDIT: Multiple selection is enabled with `selectable: 'multiple'`, but does that mean i can't select rows one by one programatically? Manual clicking (without `ctrl` or `shift`) does select one by one.

Comment: are you using grid selection mode as multiple?

Comment: @veenapanakanapalli : Yes, but can't i still select one by one if i wanted to? Manual clicking allows it even though multi-select is enabled..

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve sounds like the default behaviour is your selection type is simple.

Plese see below fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/calinaadi/FGtGy/19/

Comment: I'm sorry, i did not mention that selectable:"multiple" was enabled. Please see edit